# Invoking pyspark with `ipython` specified results in jupyter notebook being launched

Tags: pyspark, ipython

I prefer using the `ipython` enhanced `REPL` over the `python` and so am specifying as such in the `pyspark` command line:

*Result*: `jupyter notebook` launched (surprising):

```
 PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython MASTER="local[*]" $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark
```

This approach was working for several years - but at the present it is causing `jupyter notebook` to be launched.

That result would make sense if the explicit command `notebook` were also present:

*Result*: `jupyter notebook` launched (expected):

```
 PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython notebook MASTER="local[*]" $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark
```

Given that the `notebook` is *not* specified then why is the notebook launched instead of the `REPL` ?

*Note*: when using `ipython` alone on the command line via

*Result*: `ipython REPL` launched (expected):

```
    ipython
```

the `REPL` *is* launched (and not the `jupyter notebook`).

Comment: did you set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS to notebook?

Comment: the ` PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` are being specified in the command line above (you can see it) so there should be no ambiguity. Oh wait - the `_OPTS` !  Nice catch .. hold on..   Yes that's it - I don't remember having done that. Please make an answer

Comment: if you have followed https://gist.github.com/tommycarpi/f5a67c66a8f2170e263c, then you could have done it when you just copy pasted it

Comment: I've been doing `pyspark` (with `ipython`) since 2014 - but looks like had added an option to the `bash` about six months ago. I did not remember that.

Comment: Wow, happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might have set `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` variable to "notebook". this will cause to open jupyter notebook